# Elaborating $a$ in $\sum_{i=0}^{k} (a_i 10^i)$

Tags: summation, integers

I found this summation in https://oeis.org/A067030, but I don't understand the basic claim that:

> Any $(k+1)$-digit number $N$ can be represented as:

a.

$$N = \sum_{i=0}^{k} (a_i 10^i)$$

At the end it is stated that:

b.

$$N+Rev(N) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i(10^i+10^{k-i})$$

How would you get for example integer $110 =37+73$ from the above summation? I understand $k$ being the number of digits. But does it refer to the result $(110 \rightarrow 3)$ or the input $(37,73 \rightarrow 2)$ in equation b.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $N=37$, we kave $k=1$, so the claim is that $73=\sum_{i=0}^ka_i10^i$ for suitable $a_i$. Of course, this just says $37=a_0+10a_1$ and we can (in fact, must) pick $a_0=7$ and $a_1=3$.
This makes $\operatorname{rev}(N)=\sum_{i=0}^ka_i10^{k-i}=10a_0+a_1=70+3=73$
and $N+\operatorname{rev}(N)=\sum_{i=0}^ka_i(10^i+10^{k-i})=a_0\cdot 11+a_1\cdot 11=110.$

Comment: Ah, $ai$ was $a_i$ infact. That explains and makes sense now.

Comment: I have edited $ai$ to $a_i$. Please check whether this is correct.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It wasn't obvious from the oeis comment.